# ResolveUrl not working in master page in asp.net

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, master-pages, resolveurl

Ok, I have some code and sanapshot to explain my problem,

I have a master page `Main.Master` in which I have includes all the references of `css` and `jquery` as

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Main.master.cs" Inherits="CTVideos.Main" %>
<%@ Register Src="uc/LeftNav.ascx" TagName="LeftNav" TagPrefix="uc4" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Video</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    <!-- Style Sheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%#ResolveUrl("~/css/bootstrap.min.css") %>" />
    <!-- Font Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%#ResolveUrl("~/css/font-awesome.min.css") %>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%#ResolveUrl("~/css/ionicons.min.css") %>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%#ResolveUrl("~/css/socicon-styles.css") %>" />
    <!-- Font Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%#ResolveUrl("~/css/hover-min.css") %>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%#ResolveUrl("~/css/owl.carousel.css") %>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%#ResolveUrl("~/css/animate.css") %>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%#ResolveUrl("~/css/css-menu.css") %>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%#ResolveUrl("~/css/loader.css") %>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%#ResolveUrl("~/css/styles.css") %>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%#ResolveUrl("~/css/responsive.css") %>" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body id="index-v2">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <uc1:LeftNav runat="server" ID="LeftNav" />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cpl_chlid" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="<%#ResolveUrl("~/js/wow.min.js")%>"></script>
    <script src="<%#ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js")%>"></script>
    <script src="<%#ResolveUrl("~/js/bootstrap.min.js")%>"></script>
    <script src="<%#ResolveUrl("~/js/owl.carousel.min.js")%>"></script>
    <script src="<%#ResolveUrl("~/js/css-menu.js")%>"></script>
    <script src="<%#ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery.validate.js")%>"></script>
    <script src="<%#ResolveUrl("~/js/custom.js")%>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And in `Main.Master` page load event

```
public partial class Main : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Header.DataBind();
    }
}
```

And root directory of my project is like that

[image]

`WebForm1`, `WebForm2` and other WebForms inside the View folder are inherited from the `Main.Master` page. `WebForm1`, `WebForm2` are loaded fine as expected but all the WebForms inside View folder are not loaded properly, there design is disturbed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove ResolveUrl from all css files and attach them simple beacuse ResolveUrl is needed only for scripts. Just remove the ResolveUrl from css files and it will work perfectly.

Solution 2 -

You can replace `#` sign with `=` in ResolveUrl

Example

`<%# ResolveUrl("~/js/wow.min.js") %>`
With
`<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/wow.min.js") %>`

Solution 2 worked for me.

Comment: Just to say that it worked for me; just changed "#" for "=" and the css file loaded ...